# Splash screen becomes magneta when overlay is used

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am overlaying splash screen with an image. When image is overlayed the splash screen becomes magenta and red instead of gray and green color. Any ideas why that would happen and how can I fix it? My code is similar as [this one](https://github.com/nasa/CertWare/blob/master/net.certware.core.ui/src/net/certware/core/ui/splash/OverlaySplashHandler.java).

[image]

Comment: May relevant to this https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439172

Answer (score 0):

As per https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439172, the issue is with how splash screen was exported.